# What is the best way to develop a C++ web application?

Tags: c++, web-applications

What could be the best way of developing a C++ web application? The web app would be run on Apache HTTP server. How can you overcome challenges like sessions, persistence, context switching, multithreading etc with C++? How could one utilize C++ in best possible way to make it work like Servlets?

Comment: Why develop in C++ when there are languages that better suit web development?

Comment: Because there many cases you need it: high performance, low performance embedded systems and so on. Language is just the tool.

Comment: @Alan Haggai Alavi: For example to avoid to create the situation in which every project in your company is implemented in a different programming language, which in turn comes with a different IDE, standard library, custom written libraries, programming language quirks and limitations, library quirks, profilers, etc...

Comment: nothing better than fastcgi++ http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/ for ajax, websocket++ http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp for websockets.  all other frameworks and languages are crap unless if you have to use it because of a pain in the ass client.  picking the right supporting libraries can make a c++ webserver as easy php

Comment: If you want C++ servlets: https://github.com/novalexei/mod_servlet https://github.com/MayaPosch/Cerflet

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/).

> Wt (pronounced 'witty') is a C++
>   library and application server for
>   developing and deploying web
>   applications. It is not a 'framework',
>   which enforces a way of programming,
>   but a library.
>
> The API is widget-centric, and
>   inspired by existing C++ Graphical
>   User Interface (GUI) APIs. To the
>   developer, it offers complete
>   abstraction of any web-specific
>   implementation details, including
>   event handling and graphics support.

It's not free for commercial use though.

Answer (score 11):

Use C++ web framework like [CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net) if you like web-like
development, it is oriented for high performance and works with .

It provides:

- FastCGI, SCGI and CGI interfaces.
- Form processing and validation
- HTML Templates system
- Session management
- Cache system
- Transparent scale up to numerous servers.

You may give a try to [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) but it is much more
like writing GUI using browser rather then traditional web development tool.

Comment: I'm waiting for its Windows port

Answer (score 7):

I'm saying this as a C++ developer...

I would probably consider using Java instead.  Since Java is much more commonly used for this, you'll find way more existing libraries to leverage.  If you ever want to hire more people, you'll have an easier time finding web-app Java developers than web-app C++ developers.

If you insist using C++, check out:

http://rudeserver.com/

Comment: I'm saying this as a Java developer... Java has a huge footprint and will not work on a 128MB VPS.

Comment: @User1 lulz.  true.  i can run a ws++ server with ~0 memory that will vastly outperform

Answer (score 3):

You can use Qt framework, Boost & Poco libraries to do web development in C++. Qt & Poco have DB support for various RDBMS. You may look into Axis C++ if you need to develop web services in C++. ClearSilver has C library to handle CGI and you can use C++ on top of it. Plenty of choices for you!

Comment: I'd like to add-on to the_drow's answer.

Wt is licensed under GPL v2 so you can use it for commercial purposes without redistributing source code if:

1. You don't ship binaries to users

2. Users use as a web application and don't install or download any binaries derived from Wt C++

You only need to redistribute your source code in all cases when Wt C++ is licensed under GPL Affero 3.

Comment: @Viet: What if it's an embedded application?
The GUI is a web interface.
Should I buy a commercial license or not?

Comment: As long as you don't ship binaries and users don't need binaries to run, you don't have to buy any license. If you sell embedded appliances with the binaries, obviously you need.

Answer (score 0):

> How can you overcome challenges like sessions, persistence, context switching, multithreading etc with C++?

The answer is what you'd expect it to be:  pick libraries that handle issues when possible (multithreading) and implement libraries where necessary (generating a session key and storing it somewhere like a database).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Snorkel Embedded Web Server SDK. Its easy to use and produces the fastest web application solutions. http://sites.google.com/site/snorkelembedded

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with the [ffead-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp) framework, check out the home page for more information...